# My Spring JPA queries do not work with H2

Tags: java, spring, jpa, h2

This query below does not work and it generates me an exception

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM account WHERE account_no = ?1",
nativeQuery = true)
Account findByAccountNo(String accountNo);
```

```
 "message": "could not prepare statement; SQL [SELECT * FROM account WHERE account_no = ?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement",
```

When I used the MySQL database, the query worked fine. But now that I am using the H2 database, it suddenly does not work. Why? How do I fix this?

Comment: turns out the problem was in my statement, i put "account.account" i forgot the scheme was not called "account". I simply had to omit the schema name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to use JPA.

If you still wanna use nativeQuery, use like this:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM account WHERE account_no = :account_no",
nativeQuery = true)
Account findByAccountNo(@Param("account_no") String accountNo);
```

Comment: Thanks chief. That did the trick somehow

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here, but the parameter syntax "?1" probably is not valid for H2.

There's no need to use a native query here, and if you use Jpa syntax instead, it should work.

Also, you shouldn't need to specify a query here at all - Spring Jpa should generate the query for you.