# Query annotation does not work with H2 database

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, h2

I am writing a java program using Spring framework. And for the unit test, I use H2 database since it's an in-memory database. But it didn't work properly. For the code below, using the JPA method works fine, but the Query annotation raise exceptions.

DAO

```
public interface TargetDiskRepository extends JpaRepository<TargetDiskEntity, Long>,
        JpaSpecificationExecutor<TargetDiskEntity> {

    List<TargetDiskEntity> findByNodeId(String nodeId);

    List<TargetDiskEntity> findByNodeIdAndDiskStateAndTrtype(String nodeId, DiskState diskState, String trtype);

    Optional<TargetDiskEntity> findByDiskId(String diskId);

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "UPDATE m_target_disk SET disk_state = :tar_state WHERE "  +
        "disk_state = :ori_state AND disk_id = :disk_id", nativeQuery = true)
    int updateDiskStateByDiskId(@Param("disk_id") String diskId, @Param("ori_state") String originState, @Param("tar_state") String targetState);

    @Transactional
    void deleteByNodeId(String nodeId);          
}
```

Entity

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Entity
@Table(name = "m_target_disk", indexes = {
            @Index(name = "idx_unique_node_disk", columnList = "`node_id`, `serial_number`", unique = true)})
@EntityListeners({AuditingEntityListener.class})
public class TargetDiskEntity implements Auditable<String, Long, LocalDateTime> {

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "`disk_id`")
    private String diskId;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "`node_id`")
    private String nodeId;

    @Column(name = "`total_capacity_gib`")
    private int totalCapacityGib;

    @Column(name = "`used_capacity_gib`")
    private int usedCapacityGib;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "`model_number`")
    private String modelNumber;;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "`serial_number`")
    private String serialNumber;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "`firmware_revision`")
    private String firmwareRevision;;

    private String nqn;

    private String trtype;

    private String adrfam;
    
    private String traddr;

    private String trsvcid;

    @Column(name = "`disk_state`")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private DiskState diskState;

    @Column(name = "`blacklisted_reason`")
    private String blacklistedReason;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "`bdev_name`")
    private String bdevName;

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name= "`created_date`")
    private Date createdDate;

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name= "`last_modified_date`")
    private Date lastModifiedDate;

    @Override
    public Optional<LocalDateTime> getCreatedDate() {
        return null == createdDate ? Optional.empty()
                : Optional.of(LocalDateTime.ofInstant(createdDate.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault()));
    }

    @Override
    public void setCreatedDate(LocalDateTime createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = Date.from(createdDate.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<String> getCreatedBy() {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    @Override
    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<LocalDateTime> getLastModifiedDate() {
        return null == lastModifiedDate ? Optional.empty()
                : Optional.of(LocalDateTime.ofInstant(lastModifiedDate.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault()));
    }

    @Override
    public void setLastModifiedDate(LocalDateTime lastModifiedDate) {
        this.lastModifiedDate = Date.from(lastModifiedDate.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<String> getLastModifiedBy() {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    @Override
    public void setLastModifiedBy(String lastModifiedBy) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return this.id == null;
    }
```

Test code

```
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-dao-test.properties")
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({"com.sun.org.apache.xerces.*", "javax.xml.*", "org.xml.*", "javax.management.*"})
@DataJpaTest
@EntityScan("com.mycom.sat.testdisk.entity")
public class TargetDiskRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private TargetDiskRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void testSaveAndFind() {

        TargetDiskEntity diskEntity = new TargetDiskEntity();
        
        diskEntity.setDiskId("d-test-diskId");
        diskEntity.setNodeId("d-test-nodeId");
        diskEntity.setTotalCapacityGib(100);
        diskEntity.setUsedCapacityGib(50);
        diskEntity.setModelNumber("d-test-modelNumber");
        diskEntity.setSerialNumber("d-test-serialNumber");
        diskEntity.setFirmwareRevision("d-test-firmwareRevision");
        diskEntity.setNqn("Nqn");
        diskEntity.setTrtype("test-type");
        diskEntity.setAdrfam("addrtest");
        diskEntity.setTraddr("targetaddr");
        diskEntity.setTrsvcid("test-svcid");
        diskEntity.setDiskState(DiskState.AVAILABLE);
        diskEntity.setBlacklistedReason("NULL");
        diskEntity.setBdevName("d-test-bdev");
        diskEntity.setCreatedDate(LocalDateTime.of(2014, 1, 14, 19, 30));
        diskEntity.setLastModifiedDate(LocalDateTime.of(2014, 1, 14, 19, 31));
        diskEntity.setCreatedBy("test-user");
        diskEntity.setLastModifiedBy("test-user");

        entityManager.persist(diskEntity);

        TargetDiskEntity result = repository.findByDiskId(diskEntity.getDiskId()).get();
        
        repository.updateDiskStateByDiskId(result.getDiskId(), "AVAILABLE", "USING");
    }
}
```

property file

```
logging.console_enabled=true
logging.file.name=logs/nvmf-storagepool-unittest.log
logging.log_level=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=DEBUG

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:data;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;Mode=MySQL;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=

spring.jpa.database=h2
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

The output

```
Hibernate: insert into m_target_disk (id, adrfam, "bdev_name", "blacklisted_reason", "created_date", "disk_id", "disk_state", "firmware_revision", "last_modified_date", "model_number", "node_id", nqn, "serial_number", "total_capacity_gib", traddr, trsvcid, trtype, "used_capacity_gib") values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select targetdisk0_.id as id1_0_, targetdisk0_.adrfam as adrfam2_0_, targetdisk0_."bdev_name" as bdev_nam3_0_, targetdisk0_."blacklisted_reason" as blacklis4_0_, targetdisk0_."created_date" as created_5_0_, targetdisk0_."disk_id" as disk_id6_0_, targetdisk0_."disk_state" as disk_sta7_0_, targetdisk0_."firmware_revision" as firmware8_0_, targetdisk0_."last_modified_date" as last_mod9_0_, targetdisk0_."model_number" as model_n10_0_, targetdisk0_."node_id" as node_id11_0_, targetdisk0_.nqn as nqn12_0_, targetdisk0_."serial_number" as serial_13_0_, targetdisk0_."total_capacity_gib" as total_c14_0_, targetdisk0_.traddr as traddr15_0_, targetdisk0_.trsvcid as trsvcid16_0_, targetdisk0_.trtype as trtype17_0_, targetdisk0_."used_capacity_gib" as used_ca18_0_ from m_target_disk targetdisk0_ where targetdisk0_."disk_id"=?
Hibernate: UPDATE m_target_disk SET disk_state = ? WHERE disk_state = ? AND disk_id = ?

Error:
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [UPDATE m_target_disk SET disk_state = ? WHERE disk_state = ? AND disk_id = ?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
```

The sql sentence in the Query annotation does not work.
At the same time, I notice that when I call `entityManager.persist(diskEntity);` the output is insert into m_target_disk with values(null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?),  also the placeholder in the UPDATE sentence is '?'.

in `repository.findByDiskId` it works fine while the disk_id in the SELECT sentence is '?', why would this happen?

How can I fix this problem? Thanks.

I tried to see the hibernate log in DEBUG level so I add `logging.level.org.hibernate=DEBUG` in the property file ,but it does not work. And I checked the answer [My Spring JPA queries do not work with H2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71252127/my-spring-jpa-queries-do-not-work-with-h2) but it does not work for me.

for full stacktrace

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could
> not prepare statement; SQL [UPDATE m_target_disk SET disk_state = ?
> WHERE disk_state = ? AND disk_id = ?]; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare
> statement     at
> org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:453)
> at
> org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
> at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205)     at
> org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181)  at
> org.h2.table.Table.getColumn(Table.java:703)  at
> org.h2.command.Parser.readTableColumn(Parser.java:1274)   at
> org.h2.command.Parser.parseUpdateSetClause(Parser.java:1325)  at
> org.h2.command.Parser.parseUpdate(Parser.java:1290)   at
> org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:1005)     at
> org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:843)  at
> org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:815)  at
> org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:738)     at
> org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:657)  at
> org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:595)    at
> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1235)
> at
> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:76)
> at
> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:352)
> at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$1.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:90)
> at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:176)
> at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:81)
> at
> org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:97)
> at
> org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.executeNativeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1509)
> at
> org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doExecuteUpdate(NativeQueryImpl.java:298)
> at
> org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.executeUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1683)
> at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$ModifyingExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:239)
> at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88)
> at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:155)
> at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:143)
> at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
> at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
> at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:159)
> at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at
> org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
> at
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
> at
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at
> org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy113.updateDiskStateByDiskId(Unknown Source)
> at
> com.mycom.sat.testdisk.dao.TargetDiskRepositoryTest.testSaveAndFind(TargetDiskRepositoryTest.java:91)

Comment: JDBC uses ? for placeholders that is how JDBC works (so you are focussing on the wrong problem here). Please add the **full stacktrace** instead of a small snippet.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum , I will post more information. I still have a question in the insert sentence, (null,?,?,...?) why the first parameter is null, I think it should be the id?

Comment: The id is autogenerated in the DB server

Comment: I see, Thank @tgdavies. So the problem should be somewhere else. I'm still trying to get more information.

Comment: If id is autogenerated, it should not be part of the insert statement.

Comment: I suspect the culprit is all the backtics you have in the columns name. Not sure why you have all of those as those aren't really needed here. At least in your UPDATE query you aren't using those quotes (which are added to the other queries as you can see), which probably results in a mismatch in column names.

Comment: Thank you very much @M.Deinum! It works, I delete those backtics, and the the sql operation works fine! I'm not really into database, this sentence works fine for mysql but not for h2. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @M.Deinum , The backtics caused the problem. `col` is really different from col.